# Why, intuitively, does the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ but not $\ln(1+x)$ converge globally?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

So we all know that, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

And that

$$\ln (1+x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k$$

But that this only holds for $x\in(-1,1]$.

My question is, given that one is a simple, shape-preserving transformation of the other, why should we expect the former to be readily approximated *globally* by polynomials while this is only possible *locally* for the former?

I know that mathematically this comes basically from the discontinuity in the derivative of $\ln (1+x)$; I'm trying to understand how we get "global information" at $x=0$ from $e^x$, but somehow this global information is destroyed when we flip the curve about $y=x$.

What is it that allows polynomials to fit this curve "vertically" but not "horizontally"?

Comment: I wouldn't say that flipping the curve destroys the "global information". In case of the logarithm you can still retrieve the whole function from the data in the vicinity of one point by analytic continuation.

Comment: @DanShved thanks, that's a great point. How about a reason (intiuitive) why the one-dimensional reals are insufficient in this case?

Comment: In simple terms, $e^z$ behaves nicely on all of the complex plane while $\log(1+z)$ doesn't behave nicely at $-1$ so it's as far as your series can converge. If you look at $\log(2+z)$ it converges for wider range of $z$'s, for example.

Answer (score 2):

let $L:x \mapsto \log(1+x)$ and $E:x \mapsto e^x$. $E$ we know to be entire.  suppose $L$ were entire. then the composition: $G = E \circ (-L)$ must also be entire. but $G: x \mapsto \frac1{1+x}$ which has a simple pole at $x=-1$

as Dan Shved noted in his comment on your question there is no actual *loss of information* because $\log(1+x)$ is a translate of $\log x$ and you will see that the graphs of $e^x$ and $\log x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are mirror images in the line $y=x$

Comment: I know nothing about entire functions, so this is no help. Anyway, the Wikipedia page on the topic in fact cites natural log as an example of a function that is specifically _not_ entire.

Answer (score 1):

How can $\log(1+x)$ have a convergent Maclaurin series for $x\le-1$?

Your question actually hints at something deeper. Consider instead the function $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$. This is defined on all of $\mathbb R$, and at every point it has a Maclaurin series with nonzero radius of convergence. However,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}$$
does not converge for $|x|>1$. Asking why *this* function does not have a globally convergent Maclaurin series is a more interesting question, and the answer lies in complex analysis. I'll leave you to think about it.

EDIT: It seems like you are really asking why intervals of convergence must be symmetric. Let's look at a simple example: $\sum_n x^n$. In this case, you can explicitly work out the partial sums and note that the series converges if $|x|<1$. However, if $|x|>1$ then we are summing larger and larger terms, so of course there will be no convergence.

Now for a general power series $\sum_na_nx^n$, the radius of convergence is, *very* roughly speaking, the number $\rho$ such that: if $|x|<\rho$, $|a_nx^n|\le y^n$ for all large enough $n$, where $0\le y<1$, and and if $|x|>\rho$, $|a_nx^n|\ge z^n$ for infinitely many $n$, where $z>1$. Comparing with our previous series gives appropriate convergence/divergence conclusions.

The point is, we are only ever interested in $|x|$. If the expansion is about $x_0$, i.e. $\sum_na_n(x-x_0)^n$, everything still holds only now we are interested in $|x-x_0|^n$, so the interval of convergence will be $(x_0-\rho,x_0+\rho)$ rather than $(-\rho,\rho)$. This (hopefully) explains why intervals of convergence must always be symmetric.

This extends to complex analysis as I alluded to earlier in the following way. Suppose now we are interested in the power series $\sum_na_nz^n$, where $z$ is now allowed to be a complex number (and if you like the sequence $(a_n)$ may also be complex). The exact same arguments above still work; convergence will be determined by $|z|$ (except on boundary cases, which we shall ignore). Why then should my function $f$ defined above have radius of convergence $1$ about the origin, even though it is analytic everywhere? Well, once we consider the *complex* function $f(z)$, it becomes rather clear; this function has a singularity at $z=\pm i$, so the radius of convergence can certainly be no more than $1$.

Comment: Globally for $\ln(1+x)$ would of course mean on its domain

Comment: also, I haven't studied complex analysis in nearly 10 years, so a cliffhanger is not what I'm after here.

Comment: I have edited in further information now that I am more clear on what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

My best answer is that if we consider the derivative, we get $\frac{1}{1+x}$, which means that, for a series centered at $0$, the radius is at most $1$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361463/why-do-we-say-radius-of-convergence) might help you see why the radius has to be symmetric on both sides.

Comment: How about an intuitive reason for interval symmetry? The linked answer was just math (no deeper understanding).